# Firebase Analytics Not showing in console while using Firebase Option

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Below code is what i used to create Firebase instance at Run time. Code executes but nothing is shown in analytics console.

Current project already uses OneSignal.

I tried dragging "google-services.json" to android but its not used. Since OneSignal uses firebase in below fashion.

```
   //FirebaseApp firebaseAppTest = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
   //Above "firebaseAppTest" returns null

   FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions =
         new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setGcmSenderId(senderId)
        .setApplicationId("OMIT_ID")
        .setApiKey("OMIT_KEY")
        .build();
   firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(OneSignal.appContext, firebaseOptions, "ONESIGNAL_SDK_FCM_APP_NAME");
```

I tried new code  below Even then analytics is not working anything iam missing here ? Or anything to be done ?

```
FirebaseOptions firebaseOptionsDefault =
              new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                      .setApiKey("AIzaSyAe5Dkl4_29QWNzXsn........")
                      .setApplicationId("1:5765963....:android:124a58f3c0d30.......")
                      .setProjectId("superandroid-1a...")
                      .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(OneSignal.appContext,firebaseOptionsDefault,"[DEFAULT]");
```

Answer (score 0):

First time will take 24 hours to show result  in Firebase Analytics consol.